# EditText focus can't set

Tags: java, android

When start run app,of EditText visibbility set "gone" value.After in java visibbility set value visible.
I want at that time open keyboard and focus to be on EditText.I do It ,but don't work

`

```
        editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_text);
            editText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        editText.setFocusable(true);
        editText.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change it with:

```
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText.requestFocus();
```

Also this one:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```